# How can I debug/test a json response from my rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model-view-controller

I have written a simple jquery response in my rails 3 controller, I just want to test to see the result this returns (not automated testing).

My code looks like this:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
def jsonlist
  @appointments = Appointment.find(:all)
  render :json => @appointments
end
```

Can I access this from a URL like: http://localhost:3000/appointments/jsonlist?

When I try, I get this error:

> Couldn't find Appointment with
>   ID=jsonlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting does not appear to come from that action, it appears to be a conflict in your routes for whatever you have defined as your `show` action. Try defining your route for `jsonlist` before you define your route for `show`.

Answer (score 0):

to debug a json response from your controller

```
render json: JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(@appointments.to_json))
```